# sqlite TRIGGER на удаление

Tags: sql, sqlite, триггер

Всем доброго времени суток. Имеется таблица с данными столбцами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как правильно написать триггер, который при запросе с удалением строчки с определённым id выбрасывал ошибку и, соответственно, оставлял данные в исходном состоянии.

Исходный запрос на создание таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE "Users" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"Nickname" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
"Password" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: UNSTEAD OF DELETE триггер - пустой (тихий отказ от удаления) либо генерящий ошибку (RAISE() function).

Comment: В структуре sql почти не разбираюсь - можно пример рабочего запроса, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```sql
 CREATE TRIGGER "users_id_42"
 BEFORE DELETE
     ON "users"
    FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN OLD."id" = 42
  BEGIN
   SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'can''t delete record with the id 42');
    END
```

Сначала пытался `INSTEAD OF`, но похоже, что оно только для
представлений.